# Which ANOVA is appropriate?

Tags: anova

Bacterial grow rates were measured in 4 flasks, 3 had been inoculated with different antibiotics, 1 flask was kept as a control. Measurements were taken every 20 minutes for 3 hours. The experiment was repeated 6 times.

I understand two way ANOVA would be inappropriate because it treats each time point as independent, but I'm not sure which other ANOVA would be suitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you'd use a stronger version of science than just fishing for the effect of a treatment being unlikely given a null hypothesis.  What would happen if you show 2 treatments significant?  Does that mean they're equal?  Ideally you'd measure the effect of each treatment against control, and it's variability, and make a statement about the sizes of the effects.

Nevertheless, if you really want an ANOVA then it's just a one way ANOVA.  That tells you if the pattern of all results is meaningful in some way.  If what you meant was statistical test and not ANOVA per se then perhaps it's best to skip the ANOVA (in terms of inference and reporting) and go right to a test against control such as Dunnett's test.

Comment: Sorry I should have said the experiment was more to show that the antibiotics produce different growth profiles, we started at a particular concentration of cells and one antibiotic was ampicillin so lysis  was expected whilst another was bacteriostatic. I'm using SPSS for the analysis so would I just group all data for the different time points in one column and in the other column assign treatment?

Comment: If you want to deal with individual data points you really need a multi-level model here and standard ANOVA isn't appropriate.  To do an ANOVA then you should be calculating the growth rate and doing an ANOVA on the rates.  That would yield 6 data points for each condition.